# VBA to C# Value Statement

Tags: c#, vba

In VBA I indicate:

```
If Option1.Value Then
    TextTo= "Meters"
End If
```

How can I use (.Value) in C#?

Comment: can you please rephrase your question? WHERE do you use that Option? WHAT type are you talking about?

Comment: VBA is a scripting language used most commonly in Excel, Access, and IE. C# is a compiled managed language that is not hosted by any of these, but has some automation capabilities. Can you be more specific what application you are trying to script, what type of object "Option1" refers to, and how you are attempting to use C#?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what type of object `Option1` is.  My guess is that it's a RadioButton.  To get the value of a RadioButton (if it's checked or not), try:

```
bool isChecked = yourRadionButton.Checked;
```

isChecked will be true if yourRadionButton is checked.

So your code might look like:

```
if (yourRadionButton.Checked) {
   TextTo = "Meters";
}
```

If this doesn't help, please clarify.